# function parameters with different types in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, typescript-typings

I'm coding a small TypeScript function that has a `param` parameter of type Data or number.

**Error: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'number | Data'**

```
interface Data {
    id: number
}

function typescriptType(param: Data | number): void {

            let data;
            if (typeof param === object) {
                data = param.id;
            } else {
                data = param;
            }
    }

typescriptType({id : 1});
typescriptType(1);
```

Comment: What is the question? a number does not have a property called `id` as the error tells you, so you need to figure out what you really want to do with an input that is a number

Comment: It is useful to know the exact line where the error appears

Answer (score 1):

You want to specify `param` as of object type, and `number` is not an object type (it's a primitive). TypeScript seeks a common denominator here; both types in the union have to have `id` property

Answer (score 1):

Forgot to add quotes over the `object`

```
interface Data {
    id: number
}

function typescriptType(param: Data | number): void {
            let data;
            if (typeof param === 'object') {
                data = param.id;
            } else {
                data = param;
            }
    }

typescriptType({id : 1});
typescriptType(1);
```